# Count words input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I need to get the number of words in an input field. So the approach is to trim the leading and trailing spaces and also to limit the remaining spaces within the string to 1. So that I'll be able to get the number of words. Below is my code to do this.

E.g.
input value:

```
"   Robert   Neil       Cook   "
```

Expected output:

```
3 //"Robert Neil Cook"
```

This is what I tried.

```
var str = $.trim( $('#inval').val() );
var Fstr = str.split(' ').length;
console.log(fstr);
```

Comment: And what is your actual output?

Comment: @lolka_bolka: Thanks I need to get the number of words.

Comment: Yes, I see, but what you see when `console.log(fstr);`

Comment: First, trim the String to remove left and right space. Still thinking for the spaces to split ;) a regex is probably the best choice here

Comment: @lolka_bolka: Sorry, I miss read it. ;) The output is ` 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.match(/\S+/g)`:

```js
var str = "   Robert   Neil       Cook   ";
var arr = str.match(/\S+/g);
var newstr = arr.join() 
console.log('length::::>', arr.length);
console.log('newstr::::>', newstr);
```

This `.match(/\S+/g)` would return you the words without any space as an array and you can use `length` property of it.

Comment: regular expressions are always better. @Becky They are native and less number of code lines.

Comment: Not me. Just an additional one what if I need to get `Robert Neil Cook` assigned in to an variable?

Comment: check in the answer you just have to `var str = input.value;`.

Comment: I mean instead of `"   Robert   Neil       Cook   "` how do I assign `Robert Neil Cook` to a variable using your method?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below custom function for count words

```
    function countWords(s){
        s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");//exclude  start and end white-space
        s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");//2 or more space to 1
        s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n"); // exclude newline with a start spacing
        return s.split(' ').length; 
    }

    alert(countWords("How are you?"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below :

```js
str= "   Robert   Neil       Cook   " ;
str = $.trim(str.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'')); // replace multiple spaces to single space
console.log(str)
var words = str.split(' '); // count the no of words using .split() method
alert(words.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. won't this `.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'')` remove all spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
var str = $.trim( $('#inval').val() );
var words = str.split(' ').filter(v=>v!='').length;
```

Comment: Thanks. What's `v`?

Comment: Thats just a lamba expression. You can use anything instead of  'v'.

Answer (score 0):

You can Haresh Vidja's function more compact like this

```
function countWords(s){
  return s.trim().replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ").split(" ").length;
}

console.log(countWords("some words here")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look attached snippet.

```js
var str = $.trim( $('#inval').val() );
str1 = str.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'')
var fstr = str1.split(' ').length;
console.log(fstr);
console.log(str1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="  Robert   Neil       Cook   "  id="inval">
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution, try this

```
var str = "   Robert   Neil       Cook   ";
str = str.trim();
var str = str.split('  ').join('');
var fstr = str.split(' ').length;
console.log(fstr);
```